# angularJS $timeout executing method instantly

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework and [cordova-plugin-shake](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake) plugin to detect device shaking for one of my Android application, which is working fine. But the problem is after a shake I would like to disable this shaking detection for 30 second, for which I am trying to use `$timeout` like this:

```
$timeout($scope.watchForShake(), 30000);
```

But somehow for `$timeout`, no matter what the delay value is, `$scope.watchForShake()` is executed instantly.

I have also tried using `setTimeout` but the result is still the same.

Comment: did you try $timeout($scope.watchForShake, 3000);

Comment: setTimeout(function(){$scope.watchForShake},30000);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$timeout` (and `setTimeout`) expect a callback function as its first parameter - that is the function that will execute after a certain time-out.

If you want the function `.watchForTimeout` to execute, then pass that function itself as a first parameter:

```
var callbackFn = $scope.watchForTimeout;
$timeout(callbackFn, 30000);
```

After 30 seconds, the function `callbackFn` will be invoked with no parameters: `callbackFn()`.

In your case, you are invoking `$scope.watchForTimeout` right away, thus passing the return value of that function as the first parameter to `$timeout. So, what you are currently doing (incorrectly) is:

```
var returnVal = $scope.watchForTimeout();
$timeout(returnVal, 300000)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$timeout($scope.watchForShake,30000);
```

Just remove paranthesis after $scope.watchForShake.

Comment: thank for the answer and it works too but since @New Dev answered first so i have accepted his answer.

Comment: But you think its useful then raise up.